# How to detect Windows key press using the given system hook

Tags: java, windows, keylistener

I am using the code from the link: [system-hook](https://github.com/kristian/system-hook)

```
import lc.kra.system.keyboard.GlobalKeyboardHook;
import lc.kra.system.keyboard.event.GlobalKeyAdapter;
import lc.kra.system.keyboard.event.GlobalKeyEvent;

public class Demo {
    private static GlobalKeyboardHook hook;
    private static boolean run = true;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        hook = new GlobalKeyboardHook(true);
        hook.addKeyListener(new GlobalKeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(GlobalKeyEvent event) {
                if (event.getVirtualKeyCode() == GlobalKeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE)
                    run = false;
            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(GlobalKeyEvent event) {
                String modifier = "";
                if (event.isShiftPressed()) modifier += "SHIFT + ";
                if (event.isMenuPressed()) modifier += "ALT + ";
                if (event.isControlPressed()) modifier += "CTRL + ";
                if (isWindowsPressed(event)) modifier += "WINDOWS + ";
                if (modifier != "") {
                    System.out.println(modifier + event.getKeyChar());
                }

            }
        });


        try {
            while (run) Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) { /* nothing to do here */ } finally {
            System.out.println("Shutting down");
            hook.shutdownHook();
        }

    }

    private static boolean isWindowsPressed(GlobalKeyEvent event) {
        return event.getVirtualKeyCode() == GlobalKeyEvent.VK_RWIN || event.getVirtualKeyCode() == GlobalKeyEvent.VK_LWIN;//LWIN,RWIN is left and right windows key
    }
}
```

---

This code works well with Ctrl+N,Ctrl+S and so on combination.
I can't figure out how to detect Window key press so as to detect Win+e or Win+x combination. `isWindowsPressed()` seems to be the problem.

Comment: Have a look at event.toString().  The value of event.isExtendedKey() may help. By the [source code](https://github.com/kristian/system-hook/blob/master/src/main/java/lc/kra/system/keyboard/GlobalKeyboardHook.java), it looks as though this is only set for VK_RWIN on the down transition.   VK_LWIN is not detected in the same way - I'm not sure why.

Comment: @MichaelMcKay generally keyboard have only the left windows key. Can't figure out how to get the left key. Current code detects only Windows key press even for Win+E shortcut